# Abraham Twitter API 1.1 Oauth library only returning "null"

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've been trying to get the latest status back from a user's twitter feed using Abraham Williams' Twitter Oauth Library (https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) I followed the tutorial found at http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth/ and created the get_tweet.php file as my index. When I run this on my website an all white page, with "null" in the top left corner is displayed.

As far as I am to understand my Oauth keys I have are valid, I am using 000webhost.com to host my website, my webserver is using PHP 5.2.17 and cURL is enabled, From the tutorial and sample files I have been using my index file should be correct, my website can be found at http://authortryndaadair.site90.net where the results of this call is being dispayed.

I have been able to troubleshoot a small amount, but I am unsure of what else could try to get this Api call working. Any help in solving this problem would be much appreciated.

Below is the contents of the index file substituting for `get_tweet1.1.php`:

```
session_start();
// Path to twitteroauth library
require_once("twitteroauth/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php"); 

$twitteruser = "JaneSmith";
$notweets = 10;
$consumerkey = "123456";
$consumersecret = "789123";
$accesstoken = "456789";
$accesstokensecret = "1023456";

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, 
                                      $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret,
                                   $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
    return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret,
                                           $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);
$tweets = $connection->get(
    "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=" 
    . $twitteruser . "&count=" . $notweets
);

echo json_encode($tweets);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running the latest TwitterOAuth code the `get` line should look like this.

```
$tweets = $connection->get(
              "statuses/user_timeline", 
              array("screen_name" => $twitteruser, "count" => $notweets)
          );
```